# GCC and Clang: Turn off pure optimizations

Tags: gcc, optimization, constants, clang, pure-function

I'm running a set of benchmarks comparing different libc string functions. The problem is that GCC and Clang are optimizing out the computations in the loops because the functions are marked "pure" and "const". Is there some way to either turn off that optimization or get around it?

Comment: clang lets you select which passes to perform, with gcc I'm not so sure

Comment: The best way to benchmark these things is to use the result. Just printing out a single number from the output is usually enough.

Comment: With pure/const functions, you want to use the result, but you also want to make sure that you are calling them with a different argument each time or the compiler may perform a single call. Disabling a compiler pass (@Marco of course gcc allows it) is too fragile (unless you go for -O0). You could try declaring those libc functions yourself (instead of including the standard headers) and compiling with -fno-builtin so the compiler doesn't know the functions are pure/const, but better follow Mysticial's advice.

Comment: Thanks Marc. Never needed that, to be honest. But it's good to know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it! The solution was nasty, but it works:

```
volatile int x;
for (...)
{
    // ...
    x = (int)f(args);
}
```

I never use the value of x, so the cast won't be a problem. Better yet, now I don't get errors about not using `return value of function declared with pure attribute`.

Comment: There is nothing in your solution that prevents the next version of the compiler, or the current one, to transform the loop to `int i = (int)f(args); for (...) x = i;`

Comment: @PascalCuoq: I declared `x` as [`volatile`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volatile_variable), so the compiler knows that it shouldn't be touched.

Comment: You declared `x` as `volatile`, so the compiler knows that there should be as many accesses to it in the object code as in the source code. The `volatile` qualifier does not apply to `(int)f(args)`, so the compiler can hoist it out of the loop. It is a classic optimization and I wouldn't be surprised if at least one existing compiler was able to apply it to your code already. Compilers that do not do so have simply not implemented the full scope of optimizations relating to pure functions yet.

Comment: See “5. Expecting volatile to enforce ordering with non-volatile accesses” in http://blog.regehr.org/archives/28

Comment: @PascalCuoq: Ah, crap. I can try changing the cast to read `(volatile int)`. Could that help?

Comment: In theory no, in practice probably. What's wrong with the usual solution that Mysticial provided in a comment?

Comment: @PascalCuoq You don't want the compiler to know that args is the same in all the calls. If you make args volatile... I'll let you think about what happens.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: That's a really good point. If the arguments are volatile, it won't optimize out the calls. I'll try that!